# Split javascript file into multiple files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i am not familiar with javascript/jquery, that's why my question:
I want to split existing javascript file to make code more readable.
I have multiple text blocks, which i want to put in separate file/files.
What is the best way to realise it?

```
if (facet === "FACET_NAME") {
      $(this.target).append(
       $('<span> </span><a class="click" onclick="show_hidePopUpWindow(\'foo\');" 
      onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;"> ' +  info_button + "</a>" +
      "" + '<div class="menu" id="foo" style="display:none">
     <a onclick="show_hidePopUpWindow(\'foo\');">' +close_button +"</a><b> TEXT </b>\n"
      +"<br><b>CONTENT:</b> Fulltexts of all articles from the inception ...\n" +
  "<br><b>NOTE:</b> To see the image-PDF of the issue you will have go to the database ... \n</div>"  
));}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/14316282) help? Looks like either way it's not as nice as python with `import filename`

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your js file into another file with the line:

```
<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
```